# Symfony2 Render a form and redirect it to process it

Tags: forms, symfony, templates, redirect, blogs

I want to implement a form to create a blog in my website. In the controller I have two functions for this purpose, the first one to render the form and the second one to process the data and set it. The form is displayed however I cannot set it ti redirect to the second function to actually process it and add the data to the DB. I do not know if the problem I have is within the controller or the templates. Can you help me?

I have defined the submit button within the formtype.

Here is the controller:

```
/**
 * Display a form for a new Post
 *
 * @return array
 *
 * @Route("/new/_post", name="_blog_backend_post_new")
 * @Template("BlogBundle:Backend/Post:new.html.twig")
 */
public function newPostAction()
{
    $post = new Post();
    $post -> setAuthor($this->getUserManager()->getloggedUser());

    $form_post = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $post);

    return array(
        'form_post' => $form_post->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a new Post entity.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @Route("/create", name="_blog_backend_post_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("BlogBundle:Backend/Post:new.html.twig")
 *
 * @return array|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();
    $post -> setAuthor($this->getUserManager()->getloggedUser());

    $form_post = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $post);



    $this->$form_post->submit($this->$request);

    if ($this->$form_post->isValid())
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('blog_blog_post_show', array('slug' => $slug_post = $post->getSlug()) ));
    }

    return $this->render('Blog:Post:show.html.twig', array('form_post' => $form_post->createView(),'slug' => $slug_post = $post->getSlug() ));
}
```

Here are the templates:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
<h2>Post a Post</h2>

<form>
    {% include 'BlogBundle:Backend/Post:edit.form.html.twig' with {'form_post': form_post, route: '_blog_backend_post_create' } %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

--- BlogBundle:Backend/Post:edit.form.html.twig:

```
{% if form_errors(form_post) %}
<div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in form-errors">
    {{ form_errors(form_post) }}
</div>
{% endif %}
<form class="well"  method="post" {{ form_enctype(form_post) }}>
<p>
    <label for="">Title</label>
    {% if form_errors(form_post.title) %}
    <div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in form-errors">
        {{ form_errors(form_post.title) }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
    {{ form_widget(form_post.title, { 'attr': {'class': 'w100'} }) }}
</p>
<p>
    <label for="">Body</label>
    {% if form_errors(form_post.body) %}
    <div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in form-errors">
        {{ form_errors(form_post.body) }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
    {{ form_widget(form_post.body, { 'attr': {'class': 'w100'} }) }}
</p>
<p>
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Save</button>
</p>
{{ form_rest(form_post) }}
</form>
```

---

#### Solved

Corrected Controller code:

```
$form_post = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $post);
$form_post->handleRequest($request);
if ($form_post->isValid())
```

Removed double  tags from BlogBundle:Backend/Post:edit.form.html.twig

Added action to the form:

```
<form class="well"  action="{{path("_blog_backend_post_create")}}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form_post) }}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure you **post** (not "redirect") the form to the second controller. To do so you need to specify the action attribute of the form-tag.

```
<form class="well" action="{{path("_blog_backend_post_create")}}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form_post) }}>
```

When you submit the from, the code in you createAction will be executed.

(Also, remove the extra form tags in BlogBundle:Backend/Post:new.html.twig)

---

More preferable way is to use the `form()` twig function. So in your twig file, you write:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
<h2>Post a Post</h2>

{{ form(form_post) }}
{% endblock %}
```

When you create your form you will aslo need to add the action like:

```
$form_post = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $post, array(
  'action'=>$this->generateUrl('_blog_backend_post_create'),
));
```

Comment: It till does not work :( Thanks anyway for it. Any further suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you try again and if it does not work, describe the new error.

Comment: It simply does not redirect nor post the form content. The Url changes to: http://localhost/testings/web/app_dev.php/blog/new/_post?backend_post_type[title]=test&backend_post_type[body]=test&backend_post_type[_token]=BeLdPi0B36oTHlr7lP

Comment: I've updated my answer. You have double form tags. Please remove the form tags in BlogBundle:Backend/Post:new.html.twig